# Navigation Library double navigation UI components

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack

I'm trying to set up navigation in my application, it works well for simple things but I can't get it to work for some of the clients requirements, what I'm trying to do right now is set up a navigation graph based on the one activity many fragment idea, unfortunately each of these fragments have their own sub navigation (requirement) so for instance my main activity hosts my main nav graph and swaps out fragments based on the navigation views menu's id's using the NavigationUI library, but the first fragment shown holds a bottom navigation view with just 2 fragments (don't get me started on why this is poor design) so I tried to give this fragment its own nav graph, this works in that it shows the home fragment but it doesn't allow me to navigate using said graph its always trying to get the main graph for the navigation view drawer regardless of the view I try to find it with, so I tried to nest a graph in the main graph which again works but this draws the fragment over my bottom navigation view making it impossible to see or press it, so my question is how would I control 2 NavigationUI components, my navigation view (drawer) and bottom navigation view? do I use 2 nav graphs or nest the nav graph? and then how do I get a handle on them as passing the view doesn't seem to work in this instance

Comment: i found this https://proandroiddev.com/android-jetpack-navigationui-a7c9f17c510e but it raises more questions than it answers

Comment: I hope this link will help you.http://mobologicplus.com/exploring-ui-navigation-architecture-jetpack-component-of-android/

Answer (score 0):

So it was looking for the nav graph in the heirarchy which was missing my nav graph for this layout and finding the one in the main activity i found i could call a nav controller by its id from a fragment like this

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.main_nav_host);
```

which means i could use the nav graph i wanted and solve my issue